# 幅広い in this sentence

Tags: words

I was trying to understand some news on the NHK site, but I am having a little trouble with this sentence:

> 一方、**幅広い作品を集めたパノラマ部門**では、東日本大震災後の福島県を舞台にしたドイツ人監督の映画で、俳優の桃井かおりさんが出演した「フクシマ・モナムール」が、国際芸術映画評論連盟賞など２つの賞を受賞し、高い評価を受けていました。

The 幅広い作品 here would refer to a general category or would it be a category with a large number of works?

PS: It's about the Berlin International Film Festival

Source:http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20160221/k10010416661000.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [a J-J dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/178949/meaning/m0u/) 幅広い both means "wide (physically)" and "various", but IMHO 幅広い almost always means "wide range of", "a variety of" in modern Japanese. [See ALC's entry to see how this word is used in in reality](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%B9%85%E5%BA%83%E3%81%84&pg=1).

A relative clause 幅が広い or 幅の広い usually (but not always) means physically wide (eg, 幅の広い道). A relatively uncommon no-adjective 幅広の also refers to physical width (eg. 幅広の道). But 幅広い道 sounds a bit unnatural (or uncommon at least) to me, even though it's in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

幅{はば}広{ひろ}い can often be understood as *"wide-ranging, a wide range of"*.  So in the sample above, the パノラマ部門 has collected a wide range of works -- i.e. a large variety, many different kinds.